# Navigator Drawer encima fragmentos

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

Estoy usando un navigation drawer y en un fragmento tengo algo como un menú, con diferentes botones los cuales al presionar cada uno de esos botones te lleva a un fragmento con diferente contenido, para lograr esto puse el código de abajo,
Lo que pasa es que al presionar dos  botones de los 5 el contenido de el fragmento se encima con el fragmento del "menú", (donde están los botones), no se porque dado que use el mismo código para todos los botones funciona en los otros menos en dos.

XML:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/boton3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Consultar Reporte"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

JAVA:

```
Button boton03;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    boton03 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.boton3);

    boton03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new Reportes();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: los background de los layouts de esos fragmentos tienen color?

Comment: No no tienen color, ninguno @armen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

necesitas agregar un color al background del xml de los fragments y así no se vean "transparentes", o bien prueba con:

```
android:background="?android:colorBackground"
```

Comment: Gracias, ayer por tu comentario pude solucionarlo con lo que me acabas de decir, agregar color al fragmento, gracias de nuevo!